# What is the source of this error: does not have a signature matching the target?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ui-testing

I am trying to make some uitests work. I am using visual studio 2017. I am developing a cross-platform app using .net c# xamarin. It is not a form project.

I already tried to deploy my app with and without a signed apk but the error is still triggered. First, I was having this: Timed out waiting for the result of ClearAppData2 when running Xamarin UI Tests for Android, but I realized that I forgot to include Xamarin.UITest package. When I added this, I got the error below. On the ADB prompt, I can successfully uninstall com.xxx.yyy and com.xxx.yyy.test. I feel like my uitest set is trying to open com.xxx.yyy.test, but I have nothing like that on my phone (nothing that I can see). I have look for any com.xxx.yyy.test definition all over my app and nothing. The error is thrown at :

```cs
return ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .Debug()
    .EnableLocalScreenshots()
    .InstalledApp("com.xxx.yyy")
    .StartApp();
```

I am using those packages :

```xml
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.14.0" />
<PackageReference Include="UITests.Helpers.Uno" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Uno.Injectable" Version="1.32.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Uno.MonoAnalyzers" Version="1.0.0">
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; 
   analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Uno.SourceGenerationTasks" Version="1.31.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.UITest" Version="3.0.3" />
```

The error thrown :

> Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.Exception : Failed to execute:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s
>   ZY323RTCJ8 shell am instrument
>   com.xxx.yyy.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.ClearAppData2 - exit
>   code: 1 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting
>   instrumentation
>   ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.ClearAppData2}
>   from pid=8893, uid=8893 not allowed because package com.xxx.yyy.test
>   does not have a signature matching the target com.xxx.yyy

Answer (score 3):

App on your device com.xxx.yyy is not signed with the same certificate as test app com.xxx.yyy.test.

Change your code like this:

```
return ConfigureApp
    .Android
    .KeyStore("pathToKeyStore", "storePassword", "keyPassword", "keyAllias")
    .Debug()
    .EnableLocalScreenshots()
    .InstalledApp("com.xxx.yyy")
    .StartApp();
```

Comment: I did exactly as you say, but still failed:

`System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program Files\***\jarsigner.exe -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A94...D0807\23248\SignedTestServer.apk" -storepass passw -keypass passw -keystore "C:\...\Certificate\Mycompany.keystore" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-287A...D0807\TestServer.apk" ""alias"" - exit code: 1`