# Android package test does not have a signature matching the target

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-test-lab

There are many similar question about the app signature, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576719/what-is-the-source-of-this-error-does-not-have-a-signature-matching-the-target).
But none are my case.

I used to have a CI that run `./gradlew :App:assembleDebug :App:assembleAndroidTest`

To save time I try to parallelise both assemble commands in two different jobs/pipelines
`./gradlew :App:assembleDebug` and `./gradlew :App:assembleAndroidTest`

But now, I got this error from Test Lab:

> com.company.debug.test does not have a signature matching the target com.company.debug

How/why the signature changes when I'm compiling in another instance? The solution is clear, just put both together again. But I'm looking to understand this Android/Gradle behaviour of signatures.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug builds are signed with the debug key, which is generated by the Android tools on each machine. The key is stored in the [user home directory](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#expdebug). I.e. by default each machine has a different debug signing key, which is not compatible with each other.

My guess is that your CI jobs/pipelines do one or both of two things:

1. Run on different machines
2. Generate a new debug key for each job, as you do not share the machine environment

A possible solution is to include a debug key as part of your repository and configure gradle to use that key for signing:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile rootProject.file('debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can find more details in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512684/android-studio-does-not-sign-the-code-for-debug-build), and the [official Android app signing documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing).